# changing database name in sql server script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I created a schema script for an sql server database called test.

I want to execute this script in the same server where the test database is found, but for sure with different name, suppose test2.

when I opened the scripts, it starts by CREATE DATABASE [test] and the name test is used many times in the script.
so how to safely change database name in the script without affecting the original database?

Note: changing name by just replacing it's name is not a solution because it's name is a part of many procedures and functions

Answer (score 3):

No need to use database name in each and every query. Just use

```
USE [Database_Name]
```

in the above of the script file, then it will consider the database for the entire script until you specify another database name inside the script.

Eg:-

```
USE My_Database_1

Script_1
Script_2
.
.
Script_n
--Another Database if required
USE My_Database_2

Script_1
Script_2
.
.
Script_n
```

Comment: and I'll leave CREATE DATABASE [test] , ALTER DATABASE [test] , etc in the same original name without any worry about affecting the original database data?

Comment: No, for CREATE/ALTER DATABASE, you have to specify the database. After that you can use the key USE [Database_Name] for your schema (table, procedure, views, udf etc).